# How to register endpoint with Google RISC API in php

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, jwt

I've been reading and trying to implement what's instructed from the docs at [Protect user accounts with Cross-Account Protection](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc)

What I've done so far as per below:

```
        JWT::$leeway = 60;

        $key = file_get_contents('location.json');

        $time = time();

        $payload = [
            "iss" => "account email",
            "sub" => "account email",
            "aud" => "https://risc.googleapis.com/google.identity.risc.v1beta.RiscManagementService",
            "iat" => $time,
            "exp" => $time + 3600,
        ];

        /**
         * IMPORTANT:
         * You must specify supported algorithms for your application. See
         * https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40
         * for a list of spec-compliant algorithms.
         */
        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, ['HS256']);

        print_r($jwt);
        print_r($decoded);

        $client = new Client();

        try {
            $request = $client->post('https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $jwt,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'delivery' => [
                        'delivery_method' => 'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/delivery-method/push',
                        'url' => 'https://test.myapp.com/webhooks/google',
                    ],
                    'events_requested' => [
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/oauth/event-type/tokens-revoked',
                    ],
                ],
            ]);

            $response = $request->getBody();

            dd($response);
        } catch (ClientException $exception) {
            dd($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        }
```

Issues I am facing:

- I do not understand well how to use JWT from what I read in the docs, what am I doing wrong in my implementation?
- The examples are in JAVA, but I need it in php and I tried reading the JAVA code but do not understand where several things are coming from.
- From the much I've read, I assume I won't be able to test these events on local environment? That is point these events to be triggered on local? Or would services such as ultrahook allow doing so? Otherwise I would have to test the endpoint straight on server.

The error I get from the code above is `Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.`

Trying the encoding suggested below `RS256` gives me the error `UnexpectedValueException: Algorithm not allowed` I believe I do lack the necessary knowledge around JWT and doing something wrong there.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Right now you are just stating that you have problems implementing a certain API. 

Rethink your approach to the problem. From the three issues you are mentioning, the first can be solved only by you (read the docs, slow and patiently), the second will be solve by reading the docs in here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server and the third, you need to tackle that after you read the docs.

Comment: sorry but reading slow and patiently doesn't help understand something that is beyond the current skillsets? I'll reformulate the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking at how to do this cross-account protection from this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#java_1 I assume you are talking about this part (Generate an authorization token) https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#auth_token

I'm using php though but looking at the java code in the page it's using RS256 instead of HS256 in your code. If you use php then you can try firebase php and they have a simple JWT class you can use. https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt You can just use the example and replace the payload with yours then change to RS256. That's what I'm gonna try I can let you know if it works after.

Comment: I've been reading this doc for more than a day now, over and over. The example I've provided, uses indeed firebase/php-jwt. The problem I have however is I don't understand how to translate the examples in PHP, also, I have no experience with JWT. Reading the doc 10 times, and I still feel like there are things not mentioned/assumed to be known by the developer.

Comment: Also tried the other encoding you advised, but it gives me the error ```UnexpectedValueException: Algorithm not allowed```

Comment: Okay I just tried with the jwt base on the firbase jwt encode. You don't need the decode part. Also you need to pass the string of private_key as $key, private_key_id as $key_id from you json file into the encode like this.  $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'RS256', $key_id);

Comment: Then I use the jwt string to with curl and receive only the verification event for testing.     https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/verification and I can see the data return when I call https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update. That part seems working.

Comment: Then I call the stream:verify api to trigger an verification event and I did receive a call from google but I didn't see what I passed (state). This part I'm still figuring out but my jwt part and the stream:update part seem to be working. Maybe you try what I mentioned to try verify event first. If you got the data and able to see the data then let me know.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#test_stream this is the part I think it's helpful to test but you have to include this event type https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/verification when you register an endpoint

Comment: Joey, are you able to get it working? I'm stuck in the part that I don't see payload or token the doc mentioned I should receive in my endpoint.

Comment: I am stuck at the private_key bit, in the JSON file, there are attributes client_id, project_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, client_secret, redirect_uris, javascript_origins, all nested under web. Is a specific attribute referring to private_key?

Comment: I think you used the wrong json file You need to create one from service account. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#set_up_a_project_in_the Go to Credentials > Create credentials then select sevice account then follow the steps til you created a key (json file) and that file should have the private_key, private_key_id, etc) Not sure if you enable the RISC API. Just read and follow the steps the link I sent you.

Comment: that's right. I thought it was meant to be the JSON obtained from generating an oAuth service. Will create a service account this time in some hours and update here.

Comment: So reviewed your comments, re-read the docs, and now using the following line: ``` $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $json->private_key, 'RS256', $json->private_key_id);``` and I am now through (I am able to at least make calls to the API). The error changed to ```Request contains an invalid argument.```. Trying to figure out what I did wrong this time.

Comment: ok I got it working by doing the following changes: used "body" instead of "form_params", and then converted the params being sent with json_encode. Will proceed to the part you got stuck and update after.

Comment: That's good. I'm able to receive data now. So beside adding {"state": "ANYTHING"} like they mentioned regarding the test your stream config. You also need to add "scope" : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/risc.verify" as they mentioned on the very bottom in their doc. Yea so add that scope inside the json along with the state when you do the stream:verify call then you will get the token part back to your endpoint then that's the token you will use with the firebase jwt decode.Then just follow this part https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#decode_set

Comment: sorry I couldn't respond sooner. Had a change in priorities... I am back to the issue and running the section describing how to verify the endpoint. When I POST to "https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify" I get the error 403 The caller does not have permission. I am trying to identify where this error comes from. Even though the registration and the url to get the endpoint details still works fine.

Comment: No luck. I tried it all, even adding owner role to the service account. Still keep getting 403 when trying to verify using https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify